# How to avoid input type file to add multiple files?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to take only one file as input whenever i choose a file i want to take new one but my current code taking more than one file.

```
 <input id="input-file" type="file" name="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept="application/pdf;image/jpeg;image/gif;image/tif;image/tiff;image/jpg;image/png;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" />
```

typescript code:

```
 onFileSelected(event){
    let file = event.target.value;

}
```

Comment: hsow your `onFileSelected` function here too

Comment: input [type="file"] always returns a FileList, even if it's just one file. To retrieve the file, use fileList[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload One File

**Html**

```
<input type='file' accept="application/pdf;image/jpeg;image/gif;image/tif;image/tiff;image/jpg;image/png;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" >
```

**ts**

```
 onSelectFile(event) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {                         
                    var reader = new FileReader();        
                    reader.onload = (event) => {
                      console.log(event.target.result);
                       this.urls=event.target.result; 
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
            }
        }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-file-upload-preview-qt5zrt